# Are the following sets countable or uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cardinals

1) $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{\infty} A_n$ , if $A_n$ countable.

2) $\mathbb{R}$\ $\mathbb{Q}$

3) $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ { ($a_1$,...,$a_n$) | $a_1$, ..., $a_n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ }

4) {$(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ | $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ null sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ }

I've already proved 1) and 2) ( 2) is uncountable ) . But I  failed to prove 3) and 4) . I think that 3) and 4) are uncountable?

Comment: 3) is countable. Hint: Use 1). And what is a zero sequence?

Comment: 4) is uncountable, since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable and for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ exists a null sequence $a_n = \frac{x}{n}$. (Of course there exist infinitely many more null sequences in $\mathbb{R}$, but this is sufficient.)

Comment: I see my mistake in 3). It is countable because $a_1$, ... , $a_n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ . zero sequence means null sequence. @RoyPJ oh, I understand your argumentation.

Comment: The irrationals (2) are uncountable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 3, you should already have a proof that the set of ordered pairs of integers is countable.  You can extend that to the fact that the set of ordered $n-$tuples is countable.  For triples, you have bijections $(a,b,c)\leftrightarrow ((a,b),c) \leftrightarrow(d,c)$  This approach extends to any $n$.  Then use part 1 to form the union of all the tuples of any finite length.